# How to get Dynamic URL With help of .htaccess and PHP for Good SEO

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

For example i have

3 php pages

1. www.example.com/page1.php?var1=data1&var2=data2&var3=data3
2. www.example.com/page2.php?var1=data1&var2=data2&var3=data3
3. www.example.com/page3.php?var1=data1&var2=data2&var3=data3

For good SEO . I need URL like

1. www.example.com/page1/data1-data2-data3
2. www.example.com/page2/data1-data2-data3
3. www.example.com/page3/data1-data2-data3

I got something  [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) but am confused how to implement it for multiple dynamic PHP pages.
i need all the variables for proper functioning of php pages

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and too broad

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-/]+)/?$ /$1.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess you should add the line:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)$ /$1.php?var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4 [QSA]
```

The first part captures the page name (script name, in your case), then each successive query string parameter. The `QSA` key tells the redirect to take any additional query string parameters not specified explicitly along with the request.